# Tag specified in @ApiOperation not overriding tag specified in @Api swagger ui

Tags: spring, swagger-ui

I have specified a tag at the class level as "Users" and have an API specified under this class with tag as "User Details". However on swagger ui I can see this api appearing under both the tags. How is it possible to show this API on swagger under "User Details" tag only and not under "Users" tag

```
@Api(tags = {"Users"}, description = "Manage Users")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    AuditLogService auditLogService;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @ApiOperation(tags = {"User Details"})
    @GetMapping("/lastName/{lastName}")
    public List<UserGetResponse> findByLastName(@PathVariable String lastName) throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Received request to get users by last name, time: {}", LocalDateTime.now());
        List<UserGetResponse> userGetResponses = userService.getUsersByLastName(lastName);
        logger.info("Received response, Going to publish message to MQ, time: {}", LocalDateTime.now());
        auditLogService.publishMessage();
        return userGetResponses;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. I was using springfox. If you are also using springfox, maybe this might be helpful

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1257

> the short answer is that it is expected. The reason being that the way these annotations are used in springfox is very different from the way swagger-core uses it. For e.g. we don't have support for constructs like @SwaggerDefinition

> In that case my recommendation would be to implement your own operation plugin that overwrites the values as per your need.